# Pivot table Fields using String Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot-table

Im doing a vba macro that creates a sheet in a workbook and then creates a Pivot table using data from another sheet and uses an array of string to set fields for that pivot table. however, I cant seem to find a way for the fields to use the array of strings. any help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub view()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
Dim field(1 To 15) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range

field(1) = "Country Name"
field(2) = "Category Name"
field(3) = "Status"
field(4) = "Type Name"
field(5) = "Subtype Name"
field(6) = "Subtype Code"
field(7) = "Assign Dept Name"
field(8) = "Creation Date2"
field(9) = "Closed Date2"
field(10) = "Channel Name"
field(11) = "Type Inquiry"
field(12) = "Status2"
field(13) = "Equal  Month"
field(14) = "Days"
field(15) = "Bracket"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("View").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "View"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Recurrence").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="View!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable4", _
        DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("View").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With

    For i = 1 To 15
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("field(i)")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = i
        .LayoutForm = xlTabular
        .RepeatLabels = True
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("field (i)").Subtotals = _
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)

    Next

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable4").PivotFields("Value"), "Sum of Value", xlSum
End Sub
```

Comment: First step - comment out `On Error Resume Next` do you get an error?

Comment: @BigBen yes a debug in `with ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("field(i)")`

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the error message, noting that is it that line that throws the error.

Comment: @BigBen says: "Unable to get the Pivot fields property of the Pivot table class"

Comment: @BigBen I think I got it it was the `"field(i)"` suppose to be without "".